# Create labels for headings with pandoc

Tags: labels, pandoc, markdown

How can I create labels for headings with Pandoc?  I thought I was able to use latex macros directly in pandoc, however, for creating labels it doesn't seem to work.  This is the pandoc command:

```
pandoc myfile.md -f markdown-auto_identifiers -t latex --biblatex --top-level-division=chapter -o myfile.tex
```

This line in my pandoc file

```
# A fancy first chapter # \label{Afancyfirstchapter}
```

produces

```
\chapter{\texorpdfstring{A fancy first chapter \#\label{Afancyfirstchapter}}{A fancy first chapter \#}}
```

in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Labels are created automatically using the header in lowercase and without spaces, but you can specify another with `{#mylabel}`, for instance this `test.md`:

```
# AAAA {#bbb} 

### CCCC
```

with  `pandoc borra.md -t latex` produces

```
\section{AAAA}\label{bbb}

\subsubsection{CCCC}\label{cccc}
```